# Combining a multi-message incoming SMS message from Twilio

Tags: twilio, race-condition

I'm building an SMS-enabled app that allows the user to communicate with an external contact.  As incoming messages arrive, I save them to my database so that they can be displayed in the app.

In testing, everything is working great for one-off messages, but I'm having trouble with messages longer than 160 characters, which are actually broken up into multiple messages.

When an incoming message comes in via SMS, I'm checking whether we already got a message from that number within the past few seconds.  If we have, I append to the existing record in my DB, rather than saving a new record.

```
// First message arrives:
record == "This is the first message."

// Second message arrives:
record == "This is the first message. This is the second message."
```

My problem is that sometimes the two messages arrive so quickly that the first record hasn't finished saving yet.  When the second process queries for an existing record, it doesn't find one and creates a new one.

```
// First message arrives:
record1 == "This is the first message."

// Second message arrives, first isn't saved yet:
record1 == "This is the first message."
record2 == "This is the second message."
```

This makes a particularly bad user experience when there's a message with three or more segments, when the following happens:

```
// First message arrives:
record1 == "This is the first message."

// Second message arrives, first isn't saved yet.
record1 == "This is the first message."
record2 == "This is the second message."

// Third message arrives, first has now been saved.
record1 == "This is the first message. This is the third message."
record2 == "This is the second message."
```

Without abandoning my plan to re-combine these messages, how can I get the messages to appear in the right order?

**Note: ** Ideally, I'd like to know *when saving a message* whether it is a first (new) message or a follow-up message.  Receiving a new message triggers an email notification to the user, but I don't want to send multiple notifications if they're receiving one long message.

Comment: @Carter, the end user is (from their perspective) sending a single long message, but we've been receiving it as several short messages.

Comment: @Carter: "For incoming messages that are greater than 160 characters, the sending carrier will break up the message behind the scenes before delivering them to us, so *Twilio will treat them as separate incoming messages and deliver them to your application in the order we receive them.* " - From the [Twilio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-concatenated-sms-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters)

Comment: Twilio employee here. I have a quick question to help clarify this issue. Is the end user (the person on the mobile phone) sending a long message (160+ chars) or several messages very quickly? If it's a long message, Twilio should be passing the full content of the message up to 1600 chars: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters.

Comment: You're right. Our docs don't do a great job of explaining the difference between SMS and MMS traffic. For instance, if you were to send a message with 1599 characters and a picture of a cute puppy, Twilio would make a single request to your Message Request URL and pass along the full body of that message as well as a MediaURL for the picture.

Comment: So in your case there there are some things you can do to address this. I would suggest deferring the combination of messages, it will likely make the code you've written to process the incoming messages cleaner. In your view (assuming you're using MVC to structure your application) you can then take those separate records and combine them for display to the end user.

Comment: @CarterRabasa thanks for the suggestion - let me think about how that would work.  I'm worried about the complexity it would add to the application.  Right now, all processing is happening immediately when we get the messages.  If I defer the combining, then I need some way to know when to go back and look for messages to combine, recognize how to combine them, and how to display the messages to my end-users in the meantime.  All doable, but adds more complexity than I'd be factoring out of the initial save logic.

Comment: The problem with Twilio is that the requests to your server can also come in a random order. (last segment before first segment, etc.) As Far as I investigated, they do not support inbound SMS longer than 160 chars. I did discover that Nexmo is a similar provider that helps you know how to reconstruct the broken up incoming SMS.