# How to concatenate long incoming text in twilio

Tags: twilio

I'm using Twilio to send/receive texts. When I receive a long text message beyond 160 character, it comes in as multiple segments appearing as individual text messages. Is there anyway to identify them as different segments of the same text and concatenate them? I'm using Twilio's Java helper libraries. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I found this related post where some answers imply that a long incoming text should be sent to our app from Twilio in a single call but in our experience, when the end user sends a long text from their mobile phone, Twilio is making several calls with different segments of the incoming text messages. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025795/combining-a-multi-message-incoming-sms-message-from-twilio?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Twilio has a feature in beta to deal with this, and it works.  You can ask Twilio to turn on multipart message segment info for your account.  This gets you three new parameters for an incoming SMS:

```
   "SegmentNum"      # The order of this SMS Sid in relation to the total number of segments.
   "TotalSegments"   # total parts of multipart msg
   "ConcatRef"       # reference number or ID of the original message over 160 characters.
```

Reassembly is your problem, but it's not hard.  Multipart SMS messages come in parts, sent separately by the sending phone.  All parts of the same message have the same ConcatRef and source phone number.  (ConcatRef is a small number, usually < 256, generated by the sender, not Twilio.)  TotalSegments appears in each part and is the total number of parts of the message.  SegmentNum is numbered from 0 to TotalSegments-1.  When you have all the parts, you can reassemble the message by concatenating the Body fields in SegmentNum order.

Any leftover parts that don't match within a few minutes should be treated as errors.  Don't keep them indefinitely, because ConcatRef numbers will cycle after a few hundred messages and mess up reassembly of future messages.  (This was a known IOS and Android bug. Both keep unmatched message parts forever, resulting in strange reassemblies with old message parts. Drives users nuts.)

Answer (score 1):

With the Messages resource URI, you can send messages containing up to 1600 characters. Learn about the  functionality [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message). 
**Note**: the  resource URI is deprecated and does not support >160 characters.

For outgoing messages, concatenated messages are supported when sending messages to most carriers* in the United States and Canada. With the Messages resource URI, you can send messages containing up to 1600 characters. When we receive your request, Twilio will auto segment messages with more than 160 characters and the messages will be automatically reassembled on the destination handset.

You may also send messages over 160 characters to international phone numbers, but very likely they will appear as multiple messages on the destination handset.

For incoming messages that are greater than 160 characters, the sending carrier will break up the message behind the scenes before delivering them to us, so Twilio will treat them as separate incoming messages and deliver them to your application in the order we receive them.

Referred: [Source](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-concatenated-sms-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters)

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for your answer and also the pointer. A quick follow up question. There is a parameter called "num_segments". When Twilio passes us broken up incoming texts, will it provide us any indication to know that they are parts of a bigger text, perhaps using "num_segments" or other "meta-data"? 

In other words, is there any indication whatsoever to help us combine the pieces into one, similar to how the phone instruments are able to do? 

Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: I was unable to find, how to access segments and in what is its structure, but I found a link related to your problem. See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24184/combining-incoming-sms-message-from-twilio and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdDc95_nq2w&feature=youtu.be . Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks again Gaurav. This helps at least give me the full picture of the issue and it's good to know that perhaps there is no simple and fool-proof way to do this automatically yet. Hopefully in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio now does reassembly on their servers. So all this is now unnecessary.